# Entry fields in Ruby returning "Can't be blank" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've checked the other answers floating around, but haven't found one that solves my issue, as removing "attr_accessor" from my validations gives me an error that states "password_confirm is an undefined method". I built this application and, initially, was able to create new users from the login/registration page. Now, when I try to create a new user, I get two conflicting errors that I can't quite figure out. One is a rollback that says "User Exists", though the user doesn't show in my database. The other is that I get the error messages "Password can't be blank" and "Password Confirmation can't be blank," despite the fact that both fields have been filled in.

This is my controller code:

```
    def create
    user = User.create(name:params[:name], alias:params[:alias], email:params[:email], password:params[:password], password_confirmation:params[:password_confirm])
    if !user.errors.messages.empty?
      puts '********'
      puts user.errors.full_messages
      puts '********'
      flash[:errors] = user.errors.messages
      redirect_to '/users'
    else user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      puts '********'
      puts user.errors.full_messages
      puts '********'
      session[:id] = user.id
      redirect_to "/ideas"
    end
  end
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <div class="">
  <h3>Register Here:</h3>
  <form action="/users/create" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
    Name:<input type="text" name='name'><br>
    Alias:<input type="text" name='alias'><br>
    Email Address:<input type="text" name='email'><br>
    Password:<input type="text" name='password'><br>
    <p>* Password must be at least 8 characters.</p>
    Confirm Password:<input type="text" name="password_confirm"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :ideas
  has_many :likes
  attr_accessor :password_confirm, :password
  email_regex = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)\z/i
  validates :name, presence: {message: ["Name can't be blank"]}
  validates :alias, presence: {message: ["Alias can't be blank"]}
  validates :password, presence: {message: ["Password can't be blank"]}, :on => :create, length: {minimum: 8}
  validates :password_confirm, presence: {message:["Password Confirmation can't be blank"]}, :on => :create
  validates :email, presence: {message: ["Email name can't be blank"]}, :format => { :with => email_regex}, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}, :on => :create
  def total_likes
    self.likes.sum(:count)
  end
  def total_posts
    self.ideas.sum(:user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: fyi your syntax is not correct here: `else user && user.authenticate(params[:password])` should be "else if"

Comment: The use of "else" has worked in all previous applications I built with the same validations. I tried changing it in this one to see if it had any effect, and it didn't. My understanding is that "elsif" should be used if there is more than one check that follows, and "else" if there is only one?

Comment: sorry, yes it's `elsif` not javascript's `else if`. It may not raise a syntax error but it's not the same thing. When using `else` you wouldn't put anything on the same line

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line, it messes up how ActiveRecord handles things for you.

```
attr_accessor :password_confirm, :password
```

Comment: If I remove that line, I get the error that states "password_confirm is an undefined method".